# How do I get the form to submit on enter key only when user has focus on login input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 3 fields on a page and when the user has the cursor focused on two of them I want a certain button on the page to be the one thats pressed when they hit enter. I am using

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 

 function stopRKey(evt) {
         var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
         var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
         if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type == "text")) { return false; }
     }

     document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
</script>
```

To halt the default behaviour I just cant see how to modify it to let certain keypresses through. I did look at a tutorial http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html but it wasnt obvious what is happening.

Anybody know how to do this or a tutorial that goes over this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip jQuery, its still really simple:

```
<script language="javascript"> 

document.getElementById('myInput1').addEventListener('keypress', handlePress);
document.getElementById('myInput2').addEventListener('keypress', handlePress);

function handlePress(evt) 
{
    if( evt.keyCode == 13 )
    {
        // execute your function here
        console.log('Enter pressed while in desired text input')
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery (this should work):

```
$('#input_id').keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
       // press correct button
   }
});
```

Make one for each of your fields and point toward the correct button.